# Route login/logout to a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've created a login and a frontpage controller for my Rails project. Users get routed to `root to: "login#show"` which has the login features. When they login or logout they go to the root page. But what I would like to see is that when a user logs in he gets routed to `frontpage#show` and when the user logs out he gets directed to `login#show`.

```
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :home, only: [:show]

  root to: "login#show"
```

What's the best way to achieve this new routing?

Comment: It's up to the sessions controller to redirect to whatever path you want.

Comment: I don't see `frontpage` controller mentioned in your routes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In the session controller I changed `redirect_to root_url` to `redirect_to '/frontpage/show'` and now I'm getting redirected.